# Odd numbers arithmetic syntax error in alphine image - bash

Tags: bash, alpine-linux

I want to print odd numbers in alpine:3.13 image. I'm getting the error, line 4: arithmetic syntax error. However, this works fine in linux. How can I fix this? Thanks!

```
for i in {1..10}
do
    if [ $(( $i % 2 )) != 0 ]
    then
      echo "$i"
    fi
done
```

When I change the first line with this for i in 1 2 3 4. It works fine but I need to give a range. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you sure you're using `bash`, not some other shell?

Comment: You should use `-ne` for arithmetic comparisons, although I can't think of a reason why `!=` wouldn't work in this case.

Comment: I am running it on alpine:3.13 image, that causes the issue. It works good in mac

Comment: I know that. Are you using `bash` in alpine?

Comment: @Barmar I tried that one, it didnt work. I guess the issue is in the first line, because when I make it for i in 1 2 3 4 it works

Comment: Does the script begin with `#!/bin/bash`?

Comment: `{1..10}` is a bash extension.

Comment: @Barmar Yes `#!/bin/bash` is added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brace notation for ranges is a `bash` extension, which is apparently not available on Alpine.

Use `$(seq 1 10)` instead:

```
for i in $(seq 1 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a more portable syntax.

```
i=0
while [ "$i" -lt 10 ]; do
  if [ $(( $i % 2 )) != 0 ]
    then
      echo "$i"
    fi
  i=$((i + 1))
done
```